# Python selenium chrome throws 'StaleElementReferenceException' second time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make automation, that will do a task and then loop it.
This works perfectly the first time, but the second time it runs, when it tries to find and click on a specific item, it throws the exception 'StaleElementReferenceException'.

This is the code that throws the exception:

```py
actions.move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a')).perform()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/a').click()
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: after the hover there's probably a javascript that updates the DOM... populating the list there?  The 2nd line is where you'll have trouble... in between the time you find that item and click it, the dom is still updating so the reference is stale.  (You need to find it again.)  You can either include a long enough sleep, or catch the stale element exception and try again.

Comment: After I added a sleep it worked, thank you!

Comment: A sleep? Those are generally frowned upon.